# iOS Testing: How to simulate user actions

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-ui-automation

I want to test a scenario in iOS and XCode 5. Here's the scenario 
1. Run the app 
2. Press home button to send app to background 
3. Press Phone app, then edit the Contacts 
4. Get the app into foreground

Is there a way to automatically/programmatically simulate such user actions? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Instruments->Automation.

Comment: The Automation tool in Instruments can't access applications outside of the target app. If you want to do this you'll have to find some third party software.

Answer (score 0):

For sending app to background, you can use `target.deactivateAppForDuration()` but I don't think there is a way to access applications in-built into iOS using UI instruments.